# HTML Elements List for XSS

Tags: html, event-handling, attributes, xss

Lately I've been researching XSS vulnerabilities alot and I have done quite alot of hacking challenges regarding XSS as well. Though, there is one challenge which requires filter evasion. (root-me.org the second last webclient challenge(xss filter evasion) if you're interested) The filter isn't the best, though automatic execution has not been reached yet. In order to succeed, in depth knowledge of HTML and respective HTML event handlers is needed. Some elements do not get filtered, which, with the right attributes and event handlers, may allow XSS.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/) is a list of basically all HTML elements as well as some of their corresponding attributes. Though, what I am searching for is a complete list or database with all HTML elements joined with all their possible attributes as well as all their possible event handlers.

So here is my question:

Does such a list/DB already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements and attributes can be browser and version dependent. Most of them are listed in either:

[HTML 5 Spec Index](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html)

or

[HTML 4.01 Spec Index](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html)

with a few more older ones in:

[WHATWG Obsolete Features](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html)